# SQL Query - Converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql

I have an issue converting pricing in a SQL query:

```
CASE CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10,2)) 
   WHEN 'NULL' 
      THEN '0'
END AS 'PricePoint',
```

Unfortunately, it throws this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server** - you need to change your check against `NULL` to:  `CASE WHEN CAST(...) IS NULL THEN :.....` - first of all, **do not** put single quotes around `NULL`, and second you need to use `IS NULL` - you cannot use the usual equality checks when dealing with `NULL`

Comment: Please provide the DBMS you are looking for a solution in as well as sample data from the `PricePoint` column.

Comment: Try `cast(coalesce(R.Price, 0) as decimal(10,2)) as PricePoint`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing NULL as Varchar so it is giving error.

Use the below query

```
CASE CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10,2)) WHEN NULL THEN '0'END AS 'PricePoint',
```

Comment: please tell me what you are trying to achieve so that it will be easy to help you out.

Comment: When you use this approach, you're comparing the `CAST(...)` expression against `NULL` using the normal equality operator: `CAST(...) = NULL` - but comparing *anything* like this against `NULL` will **always** be false and never work

Comment: you should use IS Null rather than using normal equality operator
CASE WHEN CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10,2)) IS NULL THEN '0' else '1' END AS 'PricePoint'

Answer (score 0):

If this is for **SQL Server**, then you must use this code to use the `IS NULL` checks (and not the "normal" equality operators):

```
CASE 
   WHEN CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10, 2)) IS NULL
      THEN '0'
END AS 'PricePoint',
```

Also: if you want to return a **numerical** value of `0`, you should again forget about the single quotes around the value - putting it in single quotes is returning a **string** value (instead of an `int`):

```
CASE 
   WHEN CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10, 2)) IS NULL
      THEN 0
END AS 'PricePoint',
```

**Update:** if you want to return the regular prices for anything that is not `NULL`, add a `ELSE` clause to your `CASE`:

```
CASE 
   WHEN CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10, 2)) IS NULL
      THEN 0
      ELSE CAST(R.Price AS decimal(10, 2)) 
END AS 'PricePoint',
```

Comment: but after i add in the query cause the other pricing become null
For example, I have other value in the pricePoint like 1, 0.5 ...will become null after add in the query.